# Bootstrap 3 grid layout quandry

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble thinking through a proper grid layout for part of a landing page. My issue is with the arrows as shown. The blue/green boxes show the row/column layout I have currently. I have thought about putting the arrows in their own columns but then the "Step X" and summary text won't flow into the arrow columns. The important part is that the images and the text in each column properly line up, especially when switching to single-columns on mobile.

Any advice is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you post the code that generates the above layout we will be able to help

Comment: I think you need to show us the code in order for us to identify and analyze what is the possible problem with it. And not for us to generate or create codes for the following pictures above.